# Query working in native Oracle sql but not through odbc. Alias from subquery is an invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, odbc, subquery, alias

A collegue needs to work with this data in Excel. I wrote the query below. It runs fine when I run it from sql developer. But when I want to use it in Microsoft Query which apparently uses ODBC to connect to the Oracle database, I get an error that says that the identifier "due" is invalid.
But how can I name the sum from the subquery in the select part of the sql?

```
SELECT cl.clid, cl.cl_name, s.due, con.oid, con.contract_status
FROM clientinfo cl
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT clid, sum(dueamount) as due 
    from account GROUP BY clid) s
ON s.clid = cl.clid
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract con
ON con.clid = cl.clid
ORDER BY cl.clid
```

I translated the names into english so that the query makes a bit more sense to you. I want to show the client id and their names along with the due amount and an object number with the status of the contract.

Comment: Which OBDC driver are you using?

Comment: The connection dialog says "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle".

Answer (score 1):

Create a view in the Oracle DB and let your colleague query that view through ODBC.

Comment: The idea is very good but unfortunately write access to the database is not an option. The DB is part of a commercial software package and I don't want their support staff to suspect we are tinkering with the data bypassing the software.